# How to setInterval in React with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to render a dynamic progress bar in react/typescript. I was able to do this in react but converting this into typescript gives me;

> [ts] Property 'setInterval' does not exist on type 'Jockey'.
>   any

with a warning underline on `setInterval` call inside `componentDidMount`.

With react only I used `this.interval = setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval);` inside `componentDidMount`and it worked but with typescript's strict typing I'm not sure how to do this.

**Jockey.tsx**

```js
import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
    color: string;
    avatar: string;
}

interface State {
    interval: number;
    progress: number;
}

export class Jockey extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          interval: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
          progress: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval);
    }

    timer () {
        this.setState({ progress: this.state.progress + 1 });
        console.log('anyhting');
        
        (this.state.progress >= 99) ? this.setState({ progress: 100 }) : this.setState({ progress: 0 }) ;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App-lane">
                    {/* <img src={ this.props.avatar } alt=""/> */}
                    <progress value={this.state.progress} color={this.props.color} max="100" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `this` from the `this.setInterval`

Comment: `setInterval` is a method of global `window` object not any custom class

Comment: Thanks! works...

Comment: Doesn't look like I'm using `this.setState` correctly in `timer()`. I seem to have issues setting the `progress`.

Answer (score 2):

`this.setInterval()` doesn't exist.

I assume you're trying to create an `interval` and save a `reference` so that you can `clear` it later.

See below for a rough example of how one might achieve this.

***Set Interval***

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval)
}
```

***Clear Interval***

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

***Further Reading***

See the `setInterval()` references in [React Docs: State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for more info.

All the best ✌️

Comment: This does not work if I use `this.interval = setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval)`. Works if I take away `this` as in the comments above. Doesn't look like I'm using `this.setState` correctly in `timer()` either. I seem to have issues setting the `progress`. Remember I'm using typescript

Comment: `timer()` doesn't appear to be `bound` to `this`. You could redeclare or call it using an [`Arrow Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Otherwise  refer to [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).